# Can not send file using FileProvider.getUriForFile()

Tags: android, android-fileprovider

I know that i have asked related question many times, but i think i have found a close solution. When I use Uri.fromFile(), it works. But when i do it with FileProvider.getUriForFile(), it opens the selection page(with which i want to send the file,like bluetooth,wifi-direct,etc), but when i destination device, it fails (after showing some msg or does not show anything at all). In case of bluetooth, after selecting the destination device, nothing happens. In case of wifi-direct, after selecting the destination device and when that device accepts the request, it shows the message "Unable to share content. File contains no data or not saved on device"(Please see the screenshots)... Can anyone please tell me what i have done wrong? Please forgive me for asking related questions
(I am using lolipop)

[for wifi direct-Toast](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3ipT.png)
[for wifi direct-After opening failed notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Y51n.png)

manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.example.ragib.apkbackup.fileprovider"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true"
        android:exported="false">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/shareable_paths" />
    </provider>

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden|screenLayout">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

path xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
<root-path name="system_app_path" path="/system/app/"/>
<root-path name="device_app_path" path="/data/app"/>
<root-path name="sd_card_app_path" path="/mnt/asec/"/>
</paths>
```

Code for opening the choice:

```
menu.getItem(1).setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                        Uri uri=FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this,
                                "com.example.ragib.apkbackup.fileprovider",new File(applicationInfo.sourceDir));
                        Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                        intent.setType("application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,uri);
                        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Share using"));
                        return true;
                    }
                });
```

Comment: We cannot see the path of the file you try to serve: `applicationInfo.sourceDir` ?

Comment: Cant you just send and email using wifi? Try wit email and wifi first.

Comment: `<root-path name=.....`. root_path? Ive never seen that before.

Comment: Well greenapps, go to the original FileProvider class. You'll find it along with other paths...

Comment: By the way, it works... the problem was, may be, the  android version... As you may know, file Uri does not work after api level 23, and may be lolipop is not fully compatible with content uri, i don't know for sure. But i changed the code a little bit to determine android version and used file uri on lolipop and older versions. Now it works with android 7(api 24) and on <= 22 as well...